# How to create "reply" to sticky note annotation in iText

Tags: java, pdf, itext

I trying to create "reply" to sticky note annotation using iText, does anyone know how to do that?

[image: Reply]

Another question: how to modify the date of annotation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Taking a look at the innards of just such an annotation, I see the following:

1. A new text note annotation with the same bounding box
2. A new popup annotation with the same bounding box

The new text annot has an IRT (in regards to?) key in its dictionary that is an indirect reference to the first text annotation.

The creation date is stored in the "CreationDate" key, the modification date is stored under "M".  The text displayed where you see "Reply 1" is in the "T" key.

All this stuff requires that you directly manipulate the annotation via the methods it inherits from `PdfDictionary`, `put()` in particular.

You'll need to read the [PDF Reference](http://www.adobe.com/content/dam/Adobe/en/devnet/pdf/pdfs/PDF32000_2008.pdf) a lot, particularly chapter 7 section 3, and chapter 12 section 5.

Good hunting.

Comment: Thanks, I've successfuly create the reply-to text annotation with your suggestion.

Comment: @James, can you post your solution?