# How to add in reply to annotation using iTextSharp

Tags: c#, pdf, itext

I am trying to add a sticky note reply to in pdf using iTextSharp. I am able to create a new annotation in the pdf. But i cannot link it as child of an already existing annotation. I copied most of the properties in parent to its child. I copied it by analyzing the properties of a reply, by manually adding a reply from Adobe Reader. What I am missing is the property /IRT. It needs a reference to the parent popup. Like /IRT 16 0 R.
Below is the code i am trying.

```html
private void annotateReplyPdf()
        {
            string outputFile = @"D:\temp\temp.pdf";
             // Creating iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfReader object to read the Existing PDF Document
            using (PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(FILE_NAME))
            {
                using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(outputFile, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.None))
                {
                    // Creating iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfStamper object to write Data from iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfReader object to FileStream object
                    using (PdfStamper stamper = new PdfStamper(reader, fs))
                    {
                        //get page 1                                                
                        PdfDictionary pageDic = reader.GetPageN(1);

                        //get annotations in page 1
                        PdfArray pageAnnotsArray = pageDic.GetAsArray(PdfName.ANNOTS);
                        if (pageAnnotsArray != null)
                        {
                            PdfDictionary curAnnotDic = pageAnnotsArray.GetAsDict(0);
                            PdfArray rect = curAnnotDic.GetAsArray(PdfName.RECT);
                            Rectangle rectangle = new Rectangle(float.Parse(rect[0].ToString()), float.Parse(rect[1].ToString()), float.Parse(rect[2].ToString()), float.Parse(rect[3].ToString()));
                            PdfAnnotation newAnnot = new PdfAnnotation(stamper.Writer, rectangle);
                            
                            newAnnot.Title = "john.conor";
                            var dtNow = DateTime.Now;
                            newAnnot.Put(PdfName.C, curAnnotDic.Get(PdfName.C));
                            newAnnot.Put(PdfName.CONTENTS, new PdfString("Reply using prog"));
                            newAnnot.Put(PdfName.CREATIONDATE, new PdfDate(dtNow));

                           // newAnnot.Put(PdfName.IRT, curAnnotDic.); stuck here


                            newAnnot.Put(PdfName.M, new PdfDate(dtNow));
                            newAnnot.Put(PdfName.NAME, curAnnotDic.Get(PdfName.NAME));
                            newAnnot.Put(PdfName.RC, curAnnotDic.Get(PdfName.RC));
                            newAnnot.Put(PdfName.SUBTYPE, PdfName.TEXT);
                            newAnnot.Put(PdfName.SUBJECT, curAnnotDic.Get(PdfName.SUBJECT));

                            stamper.AddAnnotation(newAnnot, 1);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

The methods I have used might not be accurate or efficient, as most of the code were found by trial and error and checking other similar examples(also checking the pdf specification).
Can somebody please fill that code, which does the magic.
note: [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6523816/how-to-create-reply-to-sticky-note-annotation-in-itext) doesn't provide a code for the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please take a look at the [AddInReplyTo](http://itextpdf.com/sandbox/annotations/AddInReplyTo) example.

We have a file named [hello_sticky_note.pdf](http://itextpdf.com/sites/default/files/hello_sticky_note.pdf) that looks like this:

[image: PDF with a sticky note]

I am going to skip the method to detect the annotation of the sticky note (in your question, you already have this code). In my example, I know that this annotation is the first entry in the `/Annots` array (the annotation with index `0`).

This is how I'm going to add an "in reply to" annotation:

```
public void manipulatePdf(String src, String dest) throws IOException, DocumentException {
    PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(src);
    PdfDictionary page = reader.getPageN(1);
    PdfArray annots = page.getAsArray(PdfName.ANNOTS);
    PdfDictionary sticky = annots.getAsDict(0);
    PdfArray stickyRect = sticky.getAsArray(PdfName.RECT);
    PdfStamper stamper = new PdfStamper(reader, new FileOutputStream(dest));
    PdfWriter writer = stamper.getWriter();
    Rectangle stickyRectangle = new Rectangle(
        stickyRect.getAsNumber(0).floatValue(), stickyRect.getAsNumber(1).floatValue(),
        stickyRect.getAsNumber(2).floatValue(), stickyRect.getAsNumber(3).floatValue()
    );
    PdfAnnotation replySticky = PdfAnnotation.createText(
            writer, stickyRectangle, "Reply", "Hello PDF", true, "Comment");
    replySticky.put(PdfName.IRT, annots.getAsIndirectObject(0));
    stamper.addAnnotation(replySticky, 1);
    stamper.close();
}
```

Just like you, I get the original annotation (in my code, it's named `sticky`) and I get the position of that annotation (`stickyRect`). I create a `stickyRectangle` object in a slightly different way than you do (my way is better, but that doesn't matter too much) and I use that `stickyRectangle` to create a new `PdfAnnotation` named `replySticky`.

That's what you already have. Now I add the missing part:

```
replySticky.Put(PdfName.IRT, annots.GetAsIndirectObject(0));
```

In your code, you add the annotation dictionary, but what you actually need is the reference to that dictionary.

The resulting PDF looks like [hello_in_reply_to.pdf](http://itextpdf.com/sites/default/files/hello_in_reply_to.pdf):

[image: PDF with a sticky note and a reply to this note]

Comment: Thanks. So the problem was, I was trying to convert the PdfDictionary object to an indirectObject. Instead, I should have fetched the from Annotation array itself as an indirectObject. So the missing code was : newAnnot.Put(PdfName.IRT, pageAnnotsArray.GetAsIndirectObject(0));

Comment: The NM property is missing for the reply. I thought, it will be automatically generated. Is it reliable to save NM property in an external DB? ie, if a user edits the pdf, is there a chance that the NM gets new values. If NM changes, I will be no longer able to identify a comment. How will I generate a new unique NM for the reply.

Comment: The `/NM` entry is defined as *(Optional) The annotation name, a text string uniquely identifying it among all the annotations on its page.* You can choose which ever `String` you want for the Reply as long as there is no other annotation with the same name on the page. Once the name is defined, it shouldn't be changed. You can store the NM in a database, along with the ID of the PDF file and the page number.